# Vertically stack elements with absolute positioning using only CSS

Tags: css

Maybe it's just late in the day but I can't figure this out even though it appears a relatively simple problem.

I have a simple jQuery function which is fired when a button is clicked. It creates elements and appends them to the `body` of my DOM:

```
$("#addBlock").click(function(){
    var $block = $("<div class='block'>I'm a block</div>");
    $("body").append($block);
});
```

The `.block` class includes absolute positioning, like so:

```
.block {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #A6201C;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Each time the button is clicked a new `.block` element is successfully added. However, because of their absolute positioning they're "on top" of one another (in the z axis). What I want is for each element to appear beneath its previous sibling vertically (in the y axis).

I thought I'd be able to do this with a pseudo selector like `:nth-of-type` but I haven't actually been able to figure it out. I can achieve what I want if there are only two `.block` elements using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```
.block + .block {
    margin-top: 60px; /*The height of the previous block plus 10px for spacing*/
}
```

But that's no use because I don't know how many elements with this class there are going to be - it could be dozens.

Is there a way I can pull this off using CSS alone or will I need to modify my jQuery to accomplish it?

There's a fiddle of the example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/Lds7bktf/).

Comment: Just want more context, the `position: absolute` is necessary?

Comment: I don't know what kind of restriction you have on what can be touched or what cannot be touched but you can easily do this if you just have a containing block which position absolute and the content you are adding are just plain div blocks which would stack naturally inside of the absolutely positioned containing block https://jsfiddle.net/a0p4bjn7/

Comment: You will need to modify your CSS or JavaScript. For a CSS only solution, you will have to do something like you've done (I'm thinking `nth-child`) and create as many selectors as would be needed (you mentioned dozens). For JS you will need to do the math to calculate the offset _or_ add `.block` nodes within a container element with position absolute applied to it (you could add the container node in HTML or create it once with the JS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing this, try adding the block elements to a parent div, with the absolute positioning:

```js
$("#addBlock").click(function() {
  var $block = $("<div class='block'>I'm a block</div>");
  $("#blocks").append($block);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}

#blocks {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #A6201C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addBlock">Add Block</button>
<div id="blocks">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either handle a bit of CSS logic inside jQuery

```js
let numberOfBlocks = 0;

$("#addBlock").click(function(){
  var $block = $("<div class='block'>I'm a block</div>");
  $block.css('top', numberOfBlocks * 60)
  $("body").append($block);
  numberOfBlocks++;
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #A6201C;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addBlock">Add Block</button>
```

Or create a absolute positioned container:

```js
$("#addBlock").click(function(){
  var $block = $("<div class='block'>I'm a block</div>");
  $("#blockContainer").append($block);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

#blockContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.block {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #A6201C;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="blockContainer"></div>
<button id="addBlock">Add Block</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on existing answers and comments.

Below I illustrate how to create and add the container element that will be absolutely positioned instead of the individual items. While you could quick count the number of items you've appended to the page without a container and add a unique `top` value for each one. Having a container is more clean, modular, and maintainable if styles or positioning of the list ever changes.

The example below also uses vanilla JS, [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla) syntax, and a little [BEM](http://getbem.com/).

```js
( () => {

  function createBlockListItem( content ) {
   
    const block = document.createElement( 'div' );
   
    block.classList.add( 'block-list__item' );
    block.textContent = content;
   
    return block;
   
  }

  const addBlockBtn       = document.querySelector( '#add-block' );
  const blockList         = document.createElement( 'div' ); // Container element.  
  let   blockListAppended = false;
  
  blockList.classList.add( 'block-list' );  
  
  addBlockBtn.addEventListener( 'click', function ( e ) {
  
    if ( !blockListAppended ) {
      document.body.appendChild( blockList );
      blockListAppended = true;
    }
    
    blockList.appendChild( createBlockListItem( 'I am a block!' ) );
    
  } );

} )();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.block-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

.block-list__item {
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #A6201C;
}

.block-list__item + .block-list__item {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button id="add-block">Add Block</button>
```